# Negative value for a character constant in C

Tags: c, char

According to the book *C in a Nutshell* (2015) by P. Prinz and T. Crawford,

> If the type `char` is signed, then the value of a character constant can also be negative, because the constant’s value is the result of a type conversion of the character code from `char` to `int`.

They give this example:

```
int c = '\xA3';    // Symbol for pounds sterling
printf("Character: %c      Code: %d\n", c, c);
```

Which, according to the book, produces

```
Character: £    Code: -93
```

on systems where `char` is signed and the character set is ISO/IEC 8859-1.

My question is about this "conversion of the character code from `char` to `int`". Some characters occupy more than one byte. For example, on my system `printf("%d\n", 'م')` prints `55685`. So does it make sense to speak of the mentioned conversion from `char` to `int` in this case?

Comment: The very definition of `char` is that it is always 1 byte large. C does however allow a byte to have more bits than 8. Also notably, character constants like `'A'` are for historical reasons actually not of type `char` in C, they are of type `int`. No conversion takes place when going from `int` to `int`.

Comment: Multi-character (and multi-byte) character literals are implementation defined.

Comment: How does `printf("%d\n", 'م') prints 55685` implicate that it doesn't make sense to speak about char to int conversion? `char to int in this case?` Does "in this case" refer to the example from _C in a Nutshell_ or refer to `printf("%d\n", 'م')`?

Comment: @KamilCuk, "in this case" refers to `printf("%d\n", 'م')`. The book talks of "char to int conversion" in a way as if there are no exceptions.

Comment: Again, `'م'` is not a char.

Comment: @Lundin, the book says "Character constants that are not wide characters have the type `int`." So the type of `'\xA3'` is also `int`.

Comment: A wide character constant is written as `L' '` or `u' '` or `U' '`. That's another story.

Comment: @Lundin. You said "`'م'` is not a char." By my previous comment I simply meant `'\xA3'` isn't a char either, according to the book. It's an `int` like `'م'`.

Comment: On sane systems where `'م'` is not an error, it is a multi-character constant (like `'abc'`) and your compiler should warn you about it. If it doesn't, crank up your warning level. These things are very non-portable and have about zero legitimate uses in C. Unless you have a very exotic computer, there are 256 different values that fit into a `char`, and none of them is equal to `'م'` (or `'abc'`). By contrast, one of them *is* equal to `'\xA3'` or `-93`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1Wso3Me7a).

Comment: A non-exotic exception would be a computer with an Arabic locale, where 'م' legitimately fits into a `char`. But it won't be equal to 55685 there.

Comment: Or systems with `CHAR_BIT` ≥ 16?  Or is that now considered "exotic"?

Comment: In C, `'\xA3'` is an `int`, not a `char`.  There is no "conversion of the character code from char to int" going on.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char literal_meem[] = "ﻡ";
    char unicode_meem[] = "\u0645";
    printf("literal meem string: len: %zu, bytes: %02hhX %02hhX\n",
           strlen(literal_meem), literal_meem[0], literal_meem[1]);
    printf("unicode meem string: len: %zu, bytes: %02hhX %02hhX\n",
           strlen(unicode_meem), unicode_meem[0], unicode_meem[1]);

    int literal_meem_lchar = L'ﻡ';
    int unicode_meem_lchar = L'\u0645';
    printf("literal meem Lchar: %d, hex: 0x%04X, size: %zu\n",
           literal_meem_lchar, literal_meem_lchar, sizeof(L'ﻡ'));
    printf("unicode meem Lchar: %d, hex: 0x%04X, size: %zu\n",
           unicode_meem_lchar, unicode_meem_lchar, sizeof(L'\u0645'));

#ifndef NO_MULTIBYTE_CHAR_CONST
    int literal_meem_char = 'ﻡ';
    int unicode_meem_char = '\u0645';
    printf("literal meem char const: %d, hex: 0x%04X, size: %zu\n",
           literal_meem_char, literal_meem_char, sizeof('ﻡ'));
    printf("unicode meem char const: %d, hex: 0x%04X, size: %zu\n",
           unicode_meem_char, unicode_meem_char, sizeof('\u0645'));
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Using character constants `'ﻡ'` and '\u0645' is problematic because the isolated [arabic character meem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mem#Arabic_m%C4%ABm) representation in the execution character set may need more than 1 byte: it needs 2 for the UTF-8 encoding of Unicode (D9 85).  Note however that some legacy systems can still be configured to support encodings where arabic characters only require a single byte:

- [Windows-1256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1256) represents it as 0xE3
- [DOS Code page 720](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_720) represents it as 0xEA
- [DOS Code page 864](https://www.ascii.ca/cp864.htm) uses 0xEF

On systems where the execution set represents this letter as a single byte, the character constant `'ﻡ'` is well defined and has the `int` value of the corresponding character in the character set, potentially negative if `char` is signed by default.

On other systems, the character constant is a multi-byte character constant, which is specified as implementation defined and may actually be considered errors by some compilers, notably **clang**.

Here is the output of the above program on macOS, using **clang** and defining `NO_MULTIBYTE_CHAR_CONST` to avoid compilation errors:

```
literal meem string: len: 2, bytes: D9 85
unicode meem string: len: 2, bytes: D9 85
literal meem Lchar: 1605, hex: 0x0645, size: 4
unicode meem Lchar: 1605, hex: 0x0645, size: 4
```

Here is the output on 64-bit linux with **gcc**:

```
240115-char.c: In function ‘main’:
240115-char.c:20:29: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
     int literal_meem_char = 'ﻡ';
                             ^
240115-char.c:21:29: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
     int unicode_meem_char = '\u0645';
                             ^
240115-char.c:23:57: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
            literal_meem_char, literal_meem_char, sizeof('ﻡ'));
                                                         ^
240115-char.c:25:57: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
            unicode_meem_char, unicode_meem_char, sizeof('\u0645'));
                                                         ^
./240115-char
literal meem string: len: 2, bytes: D9 85
unicode meem string: len: 2, bytes: D9 85
literal meem Lchar: 1605, hex: 0x0645, size: 4
unicode meem Lchar: 1605, hex: 0x0645, size: 4
literal meem char const: 55685, hex: 0xD985, size: 4
unicode meem char const: 55685, hex: 0xD985, size: 4
```

Both systems use UTF-8 to represent non ASCII characters in the execution character set and **gcc** encodes the multibyte character constant as the MSB representation of the UTF-8 encoding.  This is an implementation choice and the compiler issues warnings about these *multi-character character constants*.

Regarding the question, here is the relevant quote from the C Standard (C17 version):

> **6.4.4.4 Character constants**
>
> [...]
> **Semantics**
>
> 10  An integer character constant has type `int`. The value of an integer character constant containing a single character that maps to a single-byte execution character is the numerical value of the representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer. The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g., `’ab’`), or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte execution character, is implementation-defined. If an integer character constant contains a single character or escape sequence, its value is the one that results when an object with type `char` whose value is that of the single character or escape sequence is converted to type `int`.

**So yes, it does not make sense to speak of the conversion from `char` to `int` in the case of a character that uses more than one byte to represent in the execution character set and encoding and the Standard excludes this case and just makes it *implementation defined*.**

The above section of the C Standard has been amended in the upcoming C23 version with a reference to the *literal encoding*, a new concept introduced in an attempt to clarify the case of the implementation defined encodings of the execution character set:

> **6.2.9 Encodings**
>
> 1  The literal encoding is an implementation-defined mapping of the characters of the execution character set to the values in a character constant (6.4.4.4) or string literal (6.4.5). It shall support a mapping from all the basic execution character set values into the implementation-defined encoding. It may contain multibyte character sequences (5.2.1.1).
> 2  The wide literal encoding is an implementation-defined mapping of the characters of the execution character set to the values in a `wchar_t` character constant (6.4.4.4) or a `wchar_t` string literal (6.4.5). It shall support a mapping from all the basic execution character set values into the implementation-defined encoding. The mapping shall produce values identical to the literal encoding for all the basic execution character set values if an implementation does not define `__STDC_MB_MIGHT_NEQ_WC__`. One or more values may map to one or more values of the extended execution character set.

I am not sure clarity is thus achieved.  It would be so much simpler if one could assume UTF-8 for multibyte encodings as in many other languages, but continued support for existing code bases is too important for the C Standard Committee to take such a dire route.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does make sense if it were a `char` being converted, because a `char` is not a character, despite the unfortunate choice of name. A UTF-8 representation of text, for example, uses one to four `char`'s to represent one printable character.

As an example, in UTF-8 your pound character is not `0xa3`, but rather the sequence of two bytes: `0xc2 0xa3`.

To avoid the implication to the reader of the code that a `char` is a character when interpreting multi-byte characters, as well as the possibility of a signed `char`, you should use `uint8_t` instead to make the interpretation of the bytes as bytes clear.

However it's *not* a `char` being converted. It's *already* an `int` because a character constant is an `int`. The book's example is not illustrating the point they were trying to make, since there is no conversion from `char` to `int` at all! They should have given an example like this:

```c
    unsigned char a = 163;
    signed char b = a;
    printf("%d %d\n", (int)a, (int)b);
```

which prints:

```
163 -93
```

Your example `'م'` does not compile on a sane system, since that multi-byte character does not fit in one byte. However it does compile on Visual C, since it is being interpreted as a Unicode character, which is being represented as a UTF-8 sequence of bytes, which is then being encoded into a multi-character character constant `int`.

Comment: It is highly unlikely you would encounter a system on which a `char` is more than eight bits. The use of `uint8_t` has another advantage, which would be to avoid such systems for which your code is likely not written to be portable to, since it would not exist on them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it doesn't answer my question. Please read again the above extract from the book and also my last paragraph.

Comment: As to the pound character it is assumed that the character set is ISO/IEC 8859-1. I hadn't mentioned this in the question. Sorry.

Comment: Yes, I know. I was using it to give an example of a UTF-8 sequence of bytes.

Comment: @MarkAdler, as to your quotation from C standard: It says the **basic** character set fits in one byte. C also supports extended characters. As far as I know, any character literal (e.g. `'م'` or `'c'`) is an `int`.

Comment: `printf("%ld", sizeof('A'))` prints 4.

Comment: @apadana Yes, you're correct. I found in the C99 standard a reference to character constants containing multiple byte characters.

Comment: Yes, on any system, that is `sizeof(int`) (usually 4), since the conversion occurs in the expression, before sizeof gets it.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks. Updated. (It can't be 1 though, since C requires that `int` support a range that needs at least 16 bits. Unless a `char` is more than 8 bits, in which case we're really out in left field.)

Comment: @MarkAdler: `sizeof('A')` is `1` on some DSP systems where `char` has 16 or 32 bits and is the same size as `short` and `int`.  Such architectures are still supported by the C Standard but it is very cumbersome to write anything but signal processing software on such processors.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with UTF-8 or multi-byte characters. The example was taken from a book that doesn't use UTF-8.  `'م'` compiles on OP's system because it is a *multi-character constant* (not to be confused with a multi-byte character).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI The question is, in fact, _specifically_ about the `'م'` multi-byte case. "So does it make sense to speak of the mentioned conversion from char to int in this case?" <- there's the question, where "in this case" refers to `'م'`.

Comment: `'م'` is not a multi-byte character. `م` is, but this is coincidental. `'م'` behaves like `'ab'`.

Comment: Yes, `م` is a multi-byte character that was expanded into a multi-character constant `'م'`, where the value is in fact the UTF-8 encoding of `م`. Regardless, _that is what the question is about_. The OP didn't even know it was a multi-character constant -- they thought it was a char. I don't understand your "the question has nothing to do with ...".

Answer (score 1):

A `char` and a *character* are two very different things. A `char` is one byte (by definition). A *character* may be more than one byte.

If your compiler uses UTF-8, then `ﻡ` is a character, but `'ﻡ'` is not a `char`. Well, `'a'` is not a `char` either: any character literal is actually an `int` in C. However, values of "normal" character literals like `'a'` *fit into the `char` data type*. In this sense, `'a'` "is" a `char` (mind you, for a loosely defined meaning of "is"). In the exact same sense, `'\xA3'` "is" a `char`. It is also a character on a system that uses e.g. ISO/IEC 8859-1 (but not on a system that uses UTF-8). But `'ﻡ'` is too large to be a `char` in the same sense.

So what is `'ﻡ'`? With a typical implementation that uses UTF-8, it is a *multi-character character literal*. Note this is not a standard term. The C standard doesn't have a special designation for this (and it uses the confusing long-winded term "integer character constant" rather than "character literal"). A less exotic example of multi-character character literal would be `'abc'`. In UTF-8, the character `م` is a multi-byte character encoded as a sequence of two bytes `D9 85`, so on your system `'م'` could also be written as `'\xd9\x85'`, which happens to have the same `int` value as 0xd985, or 55685.

Most modern compilers warn about multi-character character literals, because they are extremely non-portable and serve about no legitimate purpose in C.

Now we finally can answer the question:

> So does it make sense to speak of the mentioned conversion from char to int in this case?

The entity that does the conversion is the compiler. It reads your program source code, which is made up of characters. When the compiler encounters a character literal  in the source code, it emits (loosely speaking) machine code for that character literal, which is an `int` constant. The conversion happens at this moment.

For the character literal `'\xA3'`, the compiler first converts the escape sequence `\xA3` to the integer value 0xA3 (or 163), then stuffs it to a `char`, and finally converts said `char` to `int`. Since `char` is signed, you get a negative `int` value *written to the object code*.

The C standard says

> The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g., 'ab'), or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte execution character, is implementation-defined.

So for the character literal `'ﻡ'`, the compiler does it implementation-defined thing. It sees a character that maps to more than one byte between the quotes. These bytes have values 0xD9 and 0x85. It sticks these bytes together, pads them with leading zeroes, and calls that the `int` value of the multi-character character literal. Note, even though each of 0xD9 and 0x85 on their own would produce negative `int` constants, the result here is positive, because everything about multi-character character literals is implementation-defined.

No wide characters were harmed while writing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

> So does it make sense to speak of the mentioned conversion from `char` to `int` in this case?

No, as `'\xA3'` is an `int`.

> An integer character constant has type `int`.
> ...
> If an integer character constant contains a single character or escape sequence, its value is the one that results when an object with type `char` whose value is that of the single character or escape sequence is converted to type `int`. C23dr  § 6.4.4.4 11

There is no type conversion of a `char` to an `int` in OP's code.  The range of `char` is used to determine the value of the constant, but not its type.
Somewhat sneaky if you ask me.

---

```
#define typenameX(X) _Generic((X), \
_Bool: "_Bool", \
signed char: "signed char", \
char: "char", \
unsigned char: "unsigned char", \
short: "short", \
unsigned short: "unsigned short", \
int: "int", \
unsigned: "unsigned", \
long: "long", \
unsigned long: "unsigned long", \
void *: "void *", \
char *: "char *", \
const char *: "const char *", \
default: "UNKNOWN" \
)

#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  char ch;
  puts(typenameX(ch));
  int i;
  puts(typenameX(i));
  printf("%s %d\n", typenameX('\xA3'), '\xA3');
  printf("%s %d\n", typenameX(u'\xA3'), u'\xA3');
}
```

Output (when `char` is *signed*)

```
char
int
int -93
unsigned short 163
```

Output (when `char` is *unsigned*)

```
char
int
int 163
unsigned short 163
```

Comment: `'\xA3'` is an `int`, but that `int` is not 0xA3 (aka 163), it is -93. So some conversion does happen somewhere.

Comment: This is not an assumption, this is what the standard says.